# Tkinter - Left side of frame not showing

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a frame with a relief that contains a label, before I placed the label in it, you could see the whole rectangle with the relief I chose but after placing the label I can't see the left side of it

here is the code for the frame and label:

```
ResultFr = ttk.Frame(self.window, height=60, relief="ridge")
ResultFr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky= "we", padx = 5, pady = 5)
ResultFr.grid_propagate(False)

resultLabel = tk.Label(self.ResultFr, height=4, anchor="center")
resultLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: Add `self` to `self.ResultFr` same as `grid` too.

Comment: This code doesn't run, and if we fix it and add enough extra code so that it can run, the frame appears. It has a width of 1 so it's hard to see, but it's there.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `grid_propagate(False)` is causing the `Frame` to collapse to a width of `1` and the height you set `60` (thanks Bryan Oakley for the heads-up). You can fix this by either removing `grid_propagate(False)` (or setting it to `True`, but that's just the default), *or* by explicitly setting the internal padding of the `Frame` with `ipadx` and `ipady` like so:

```
# set the padding dimensions to whatever you like
ResultFr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="we", padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=200, ipady=60)
```

Also, if you're planning to use `self.ResultFr` as the parent for `resultLabel`, you need to prefix the variable name with `self` at assignment:

```
self.ResultFr = ttk.Frame(self.window, relief="ridge")
self.ResultFr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky= "we", padx = 5, pady = 5)
self.ResultFr.grid_propagate(False)

self.resultLabel = tk.Label(self.ResultFr, height=4, anchor="center")
# TIP: you should set the x and y padding of the label to at least the
# same values as the frame to avoid having the label's background
# overlap with and cut off the frame
self.resultLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
```

This is of course assuming these widgets are defined within a `Class`

Also, as a style note: capitalized names, e.g. `ResultFr` are usually reserved for classes in Python, while variables are named in lowercase using `snake_case`, i.e. `result_fr`. Take a look at [pep8.org](https://pep8.org/) for a rundown of the Python style guide.

Comment: I think the width is 1, not zero. They configured the height to be 60 so it remains 60.

Comment: @BryanOakley Good point - I missed that!

Comment: Okay I included the internal padding options but still no dice, I made the label into another colour to see what's wrong, and apparently it sticks to the northwest part of the frame even though I want it to be centred and that's why the frame doesn't show on the left side